# GIT stage same change hunk on multiple files

Tags: git

If I did the same textual changes in 100 files (e.g. replace line "aaa" with "bbb" and "ccc" with "ddd" - in each file the line numbers are different but it is the same change). Is there a way in git to "scan" all changed hunks and stage all hunks that look exactly like a one I pick (for example I want only to stage the aaa->bbb change but not the ccc->ddd change)? Is there any tool that does that?

Edited question for clarity that I am looking for a way to stage some of the changed hunks at once.

Comment: Are you looking for `git add -p`? If so, I'd also consider setting `interactive.singlekey=1`.

Answer (score 0):

The steps:

- `git stash` - before your global replace stash your any current changes (this will stash both staged and non-staged)
- Do your global replace `aaa->bbb`
- `git add -u` - stage your replace
- `git stash pop` - return the previous changes from the stash back with their state (staged or not).

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I do not think this is what I am looking for. I edited my question to be clear I am looking for a way to stage only specific hunks of change that did the same textual change (e.g. aaa->bbb) but not stage all of the changes in all files

Comment: @DaniAvni that's what exactly I've described - how you can stage your `aaa->bbb` changes. Try it step-by-step

Comment: What happens if I already have aaa->bbb and ccc->ddd changed and everything unstaged? I want to stage all the aaa->bbb changes and leave the ccc->ddd unstaged

Comment: undo aaa->bbb and follow my recipe, that's not a problem at all

Comment: @DaniAvni that's not about how to fix your current state, that's how to work with such workflow from the beginning. there's no sense to invent a solution for 1 time only case

Comment: this is not for a one time only. I did a lot of changes to code refactoring a method. This refactoring had me change 100+ files with the same change to a function call. While reviewing what I did in git and staging changes (to make sure there is no junk left) I want to stage the specific change in each of the 100+ files (as I know it is ok and code compiles). I do not want to stage the entire 100 files as they could contain other junk changes so basically I am trying to speed up my review of the changes I made